# (JS/Canvas) Collision/Movement for sidescroller

Tags: javascript, canvas

http://jsfiddle.net/xknbn/
http://jsfiddle.net/xknbn/embedded/result/

Hey guys. I'm having issues getting my collision system to function without problems. At the moment, if I'm going too fast, I get embedded in the object and my collision resolution fails. I'm fairly certain that the problem happens because of how I have velocity set up, but I don't know how I can go about fixing the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
friction = 0.9,
gravity = 0.3;

function keycheck() {

if (keys[32]) {
    if (!player.jumping) {
        player.jumping = true;
        player.vely = -player.speed;
    }
}

if (keys[68]) {
    if (player.velx < player.speed) {
        player.velx++;
    }
}
if (keys[65]) {
    if (player.velx > -player.speed) {
        player.velx--;
    }
}
}

ctx.startx = player.x;
ctx.starty = player.y;
function playerupdate() {

player.Intersects = function(object) {                                      
    return player.x < object.x + object.width + 1  &&
    player.x + player.width + 1 > object.x &&
    player.y < object.y + object.height + 1 &&
    player.y + player.height + 1 > object.y;
}

solidcount = 0;
for (i = 0; i < tgen.length; i++) {

    for (ii = 0; ii < tgen[i].length; ii++) {

        if ( player.Intersects(tgen[i][ii]) && tgen[i][ii].solid ) {
            var pright = player.x + player.width,
                pleft = player.x,
                ptop = player.y,
                pbottom = player.y + player.height,
                oright = tgen[i][ii].x + tgen[i][ii].width,
                oleft = tgen[i][ii].x,
                otop = tgen[i][ii].y,
                obottom = tgen[i][ii].y + tgen[i][ii].height;

            //if player is to the right of his previous position, and his right side has collided with objects left
            if (player.x >= ctx.startx && pright > oleft - 1) {
                player.x--;
            }
            //if player is to the left of his previous position, and his left side has collided with objects right
            if (player.x <= ctx.startx && pleft < oright + 1) {
                player.x++;
            }
            //if player is above his previous position, and his top side has collided with objects bottom
            if (player.y <= ctx.starty && ptop < obottom + 1) {
                player.y++;
            }
            //if player is below his previous position, and his bottom side has collided with objects top
            if (player.y >= ctx.starty && pbottom > otop - 1) {
                player.y--;
                player.vely = 0;
                player.jumping = false;
            }
            solidcount++;
        }
    }

    if ( i == tgen.length - 1 && solidcount == 0 ) {
        player.jumping = true;
    }
}

ctx.diffx = player.x - ctx.startx;
ctx.diffy = player.y - ctx.starty;

if (player.x <= bgimg.width - width/2 && player.x >= width/2) {
    ctx.translate(-ctx.diffx,0);
}

if (player.y <= bgimg.height - 360 - player.height) {
    ctx.translate(0,-ctx.diffy);
}

ctx.startx = player.x;
ctx.starty = player.y;

ctx.clearRect(player.x-width/2,player.y-height/2,width,height);

ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillRect(player.x,player.y,player.width,player.height);

keycheck();

player.velx *= friction;
if (player.jumping) {player.vely += gravity;}

player.x += player.velx;
player.x = Math.round(player.x);   

player.y += player.vely;
player.y = Math.round(player.y);

if (player.y >= bgimg.height - player.height - 1) {
    player.y = bgimg.height - player.height - 1;
    player.vely = 0;
    player.jumping = false;
}

if (player.x > bgimg.width - player.width) {
    player.x = bgimg.width - player.width;
    player.velx = 0;
};

if (player.x < 0) {
    player.x = 0;
    player.velx = 0;
}   

if (!keys[65] && !keys[68] && (player.velx < 0.2 && player.velx > -0.2)) {player.velx = 0};

console.log(player.x,player.y)
requestAnimationFrame(playerupdate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is a common platform engine problem. If your player was moving too fast, it would go straight though the obstacles, because no collision testing occurs between the current position and the next position. Your aim is to test collisions as few times as possible but so that all possible collisions between the start position and the target are tested. Also when you detect a collision in the path, you have to handle it properly.

## Moving objects safely

To move any objects safely you need to move them in steps, and test for collisions at each step. The simplest choice is to move the player by 1 pixel at a time, and then test for a collision. This does mean doing a lot of collision tests though.

To improve this, if you are only doing box collision testing, you can move the player by a maximum of the width of the player each time.

## Dealing with collisions

So in your example, you move the player back 1 pixel depending on the direction of the player. If the player were to sink 5 pixels into the obstacle, then your collision handling mechanism only moves the player back to 4 pixels into the obstacle. It appears as if the player slowly moves through the obstacle.

If you move the player 1 pixel at a time, the approach you have taken works. If you move the player more than 1 pixel at a time then you have to move the player back until it no longer overlaps an obstacle. Something like while (overlapping) -> move back one pixel